# Magento 2. Customer Edit Tab

Tags: magento2, customer, tabs

I wish to create a a grid inside a tab that is located on customer edit.

I found something similar on product edit (see screenshot)

The problem is that product edit is build via ui components when customer edit is built with php blocks (does not support ui components, I've tried)

Any pointers are highly appreciated. 
I don't need the full solution just tell where to look or what to search exactly. Cheers.
[image]